# dplyr::filter nested dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, nested, dplyr

Question:

How to filter rows based on a nested dataframe using dplyr:filter

---

Problem:
The following code provides an example dataset to enable a working example.

Using the example code I can subset using `which`, but I am having a problem using dplyr due to the nested data frames.

Now I appreciate I could flatten the dataframe using jsonlite, however I am interested to know if and how I might harness dplyr without flattening the dataframe.

All help gratefully received and appreciated.

```
requiredPackages <- c("devtools","dplyr","tidyr","data.table","ggplot2","ggvis","RMySQL", "jsonlite", "psych", "plyr", "knitr")

ipak <- function(pkg)
{
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg))
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

ipak(requiredPackages)

dataDir         <- "./data"
fileUrl         <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/dsscapstone/dataset/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset.zip"
filePath        <- file.path(dataDir)

# Does the directory Exist? If it does'nt create it
if (!file.exists(dataDir)) {
  dir.create(dataDir)
}

# Now we check if we have downloaded the data already into 
# "./data/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset". If not, then we download the
# zip file... and extract it under the data directory as 
# './data/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset'...

if (!file.exists( file.path(dataDir,"yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset"))) {
  temp <- tempfile()
  download.file(fileUrl, temp, mode = "wb", method = "curl")
  unzip(temp, exdir = dataDir)
  unlink(temp)
}

if ( !exists("yelpBusinessData") )
{
  if (file.exists( file.path(dataDir,"yelpBusinessData.rds"))) {
    yelpBusinessData <- readRDS(file.path(dataDir,"yelpBusinessData.rds"))
  } else {
    yelpBusinessDataFilePath <- file.path(dataDir, 
                                          "yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json")
    yelpBusinessData <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]",
                                         paste(readLines(yelpBusinessDataFilePath),
                                               collapse = ",")),
                                 flatten = FALSE)
    str(yelpBusinessData, max_level = 1)
    # Fix the column name duplication issue
    # If and when you flatten the data the you create two columns wiht the same column id
    # 
    # i.e. yelpBusinessData$attributes.Good.for.kids
    # 
    # This fixes the issue by renaming the first column...
    #       
    colnames(yelpBusinessData$attributes)[6] <- "Price_Range"
    colnames(yelpBusinessData$attributes)[7] <- "Good_For_Kids"
    saveRDS( yelpBusinessData, file.path(dataDir, "yelpBusinessData.rds"))
  }
}
```

---

The above code loads the example dataframe.

Here is an example of the problem I mentioned above. The first code example works and harnesses `which` to select four records. The problem is how to do the same with dplyr::filter - what am I missing? Specifically, how do you dereference nested dataframes???

```
# Extract the Phoenix subset using `which`
yelpBusinessData.PA <- yelpBusinessData[which(yelpBusinessData$city == "Phoenix"),]
yelpBusinessData.PA.rest <- yelpBusinessData.PA[which(grepl("Restaurants",
yelpBusinessData.PA$categories)),]
Exp <- yelpBusinessData.PA.rest[which(yelpBusinessData.PA.rest$attributes$Price_Range == 4),]
dim(Exp)
```

---

Result - Four records selected :-)

```
> dim(Exp)
[1]  4 15
```

### Question: How to do this with dplyr?

```
yelpBusinessData.PA.rest <- yelpBusinessData %>% 
  filter(city == "Phoenix") %>%
  filter(grepl("Restaurants", categories)) %>%
  filter(attributes$Price_Range == 4)
```

the above code fails... now if I flatten the file I can get this to work correctly but...

**Note the subtle change from: "attributes$Price_Range" to "attributes.Price_Range".**

```
yelpBusinessData2 <- flatten(yelpBusinessData, recursive = TRUE)
dim(yelpBusinessData2)

Exp2 <- yelpBusinessData2 %>% 
  filter(city == "Phoenix") %>%
  filter(grepl("Restaurants", categories)) %>%
  filter(attributes.Price_Range == 4)
dim(Exp2)
```

my goal however is to understand how to do this without flattening the nested data frames.

**I.E** -> **How to use dplyr with nested dataframes? **

**What am I missing here? :-)**

One potential answer that I have tried is to index the nested data frame using [[]], this does work but you loose the elegance of dplyr...

**Is there a better way?**

```
Exp2 <- yelpBusinessData %>% 
  filter(city == "Phoenix") %>%
  filter(grepl("Restaurants", categories)) %>%
  filter( attributes[[6]][] == 4)
```

The above indexes into "attributes$Price_range" and returned the correct result when using nested data frames. i.e Price_Range is the 6th dataframe of the attributes dataframe...

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] knitcitations_1.0.6 pander_0.5.2        plyr_1.8.3          jsonlite_0.9.16     ggvis_0.4.2.9000   
 [6] tidyr_0.2.0         devtools_1.8.0      qmap_1.0-3          fitdistrplus_1.0-4  knitr_1.11         
[11] dplyr_0.4.3.9000    data.table_1.9.4    psych_1.5.6         mapproj_1.2-4       maptools_0.8-36    
[16] rworldmap_1.3-1     sp_1.1-1            maps_2.3-11         ggmap_2.5.2         ggplot2_1.0.1      
[21] RMySQL_0.10.5       DBI_0.3.1           setwidth_1.0-4      colorout_1.1-1      vimcom_1.2-3       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.0.0           splines_3.2.2        shiny_0.12.2         assertthat_0.1       highr_0.5           
 [6] yaml_2.1.13          lattice_0.20-33      chron_2.3-47         digest_0.6.8         RefManageR_0.8.63   
[11] colorspace_1.2-6     htmltools_0.2.6      httpuv_1.3.3         XML_3.98-1.3         bibtex_0.4.0        
[16] xtable_1.7-4         scales_0.3.0         jpeg_0.1-8           git2r_0.11.0         lazyeval_0.1.10.9000
[21] mnormt_1.5-3         proto_0.3-10         survival_2.38-3      RJSONIO_1.3-0        magrittr_1.5        
[26] mime_0.3             memoise_0.2.1        evaluate_0.7.2       MASS_7.3-43          xml2_0.1.1          
[31] foreign_0.8-66       ggthemes_2.2.1       rsconnect_0.4.1.4    tools_3.2.2          geosphere_1.4-3     
[36] RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.7  formatR_1.2          stringr_1.0.0        munsell_0.4.2        rversions_1.0.2     
[41] grid_3.2.2           RCurl_1.95-4.7       rstudioapi_0.3.1     rjson_0.2.15         spam_1.0-1          
[46] bitops_1.0-6         labeling_0.3         rmarkdown_0.7        gtable_0.1.2         curl_0.9.3          
[51] reshape2_1.4.1       R6_2.1.1             lubridate_1.3.3      stringi_0.5-5        parallel_3.2.2      
[56] Rcpp_0.12.0          fields_8.2-1         png_0.1-7
```

Comment: I just had a quick look. So I can be wrong. If you use `which` you are finding indexes. In that case, you can use `slice` rather than `filter`. If you can provide a reproducible data, that would be great.

Comment: Jazzuro - Thanks - I'll look into slice. Much appreciated. 

You know my sense is that the issue is how to access the nested dataframe. Specifically, where you have

Dataframe$dataframe.nested1$dataframe.nested2

the dereferencing in dplyr I sense is the issue. I could be wrong but...

Comment: If you can provide a sample data, I am sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Jazzurro - the initial code referenced should load the yelp test datset and allow you try it. Thanks for your help and answer. I am reading up on slice as we speak. Take care :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 different parts to this question, each of which has very likely been answered well (& thoroughly) elsewhere on SO.

These are:

1. How to work with a "messy" data.frame in R/dplyr?

   The example you give here is messier than a 'nested' data.frame since it contains list-columns as well as data-frame-columns containing data-frame-columns.
2. How to clean up a "messy" data.frame in R/dplyr?
3. Is there a better way to work with these data, maintaining their hierarchy?

### Working with a "messy" data frame in R/dplyr?

Generally and particularly when starting out I take an approach of *iteratively cleaning my data*. This means I first identify the columns I most need to work with, the columns that are most problematic, and clean only those at the intersection.

Specifically:

1. Filter out any column that is problematic but not important
2. Focus my effort on any column that is problematic AND important
3. Keep any column that is important and not problematic

*Aside: This leaves a fourth group of columns that are BOTH unimportant and not problematic. What you do with these depends on the problem. For example, if I'm preparing a production database, I will exclude them and only include the "cleaned" columns (#2 and #3 above). If I'm doing an exploratory analysis I'll include them since I may change my mind about their importance down the line.*

In this example you give, the problematic columns are those that contain data.frames. (These are problematic because they *break compatibility with dplyr* -- not because they are messy).

You can filter them out using `dplyr::select_if`:

```r
yelpBusinessData %>%
  dplyr::select_if(purrr::negate(is.data.frame)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(city == 'Phoenix')
```

After that, the other `dplyr` operators in your example will work provided they don't reference data in columns that are data.frames (for example, the `attribute`s). This brings me to part II ..

### How to clean a "messy" data.frame in R/dplyr?

One way to handle the "messy" data-frame columns in this data would be to `flatten` each one & join it back to the original data frame.

Taking the `attributes` column as an example, we can use `jsonlite::flatten` on this sub-data-frame & then join it back to our original:

```r
yelpBusinessData %>%
  dplyr::select_if(purrr::negate(is.data.frame)) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_cols(jsonlite::flatten(yelpBusinessData$attributes, recursive = T)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(city == 'Phoenix') %>%
  dplyr::filter(grepl("Restaurants", categories)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(Price_Range == 4)
```

The `hours` component, however, you might want to handle differently. In this example, the `hours` data.frame contains a data.frame for each day of the week with two fields ("open" and "close"). Here I use `purrr:map` to apply a function to each column simplifying the data.frame into a character vector.

```r
hours <- 
  yelpBusinessData$hours %>% 
  purrr::map(. %>% 
               dplyr::transmute(hours = stringr::str_c(open, close, sep = ' - ')) %>% 
               unlist()) %>%
  tibble::as_tibble()
```

This produces a `data.frame` with the start - stop time for each day of the week:

```
> str(hours)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   61184 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Tuesday  : chr  "08:00 - 17:00" NA NA "10:00 - 21:00" ...
 $ Friday   : chr  "08:00 - 17:00" NA NA "10:00 - 21:00" ...
 $ Monday   : chr  "08:00 - 17:00" NA NA "10:00 - 21:00" ...
 $ Wednesday: chr  "08:00 - 17:00" NA NA "10:00 - 21:00" ...
 $ Thursday : chr  "08:00 - 17:00" NA NA "10:00 - 21:00" ...
 $ Sunday   : chr  NA NA NA "11:00 - 18:00" ...
 $ Saturday : chr  NA NA NA "10:00 - 21:00" ...
```

Similarly, one could use `map2_dfc` (which automagically calls `bind_cols` after mapping) to collapse the data-frames of this object yourself:

```r
hours <- yelpBusinessData$hours %>% 
  purrr::map2_dfc(.x = .,
                  .y = names(.),
                  .f = ~ .x %>% 
                    dplyr::rename_all(funs(stringr::str_c(.y, ., sep = '_'))))
```

This produces a single `data.frame` with the day-specific start & stop times:

```r
> str(hours)
'data.frame':   61184 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ Tuesday_close  : chr  "17:00" NA NA "21:00" ...
 $ Tuesday_open   : chr  "08:00" NA NA "10:00" ...
 $ Friday_close   : chr  "17:00" NA NA "21:00" ...
 $ Friday_open    : chr  "08:00" NA NA "10:00" ...
 $ Monday_close   : chr  "17:00" NA NA "21:00" ...
 $ Monday_open    : chr  "08:00" NA NA "10:00" ...
 $ Wednesday_close: chr  "17:00" NA NA "21:00" ...
 $ Wednesday_open : chr  "08:00" NA NA "10:00" ...
 $ Thursday_close : chr  "17:00" NA NA "21:00" ...
 $ Thursday_open  : chr  "08:00" NA NA "10:00" ...
 $ Sunday_close   : chr  NA NA NA "18:00" ...
 $ Sunday_open    : chr  NA NA NA "11:00" ...
 $ Saturday_close : chr  NA NA NA "21:00" ...
 $ Saturday_open  : chr  NA NA NA "10:00" ...
```

Rather than put important information in the field names, however, you might prefer to "denormalize" some data, to produce a more tidy structure:

```r
> purrr::flatten_dfr(yelpBusinessData$hours, .id = 'day')
# A tibble: 61,184 x 3
   day   close open 
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 1     NA    NA   
 2 1     NA    NA   
 3 1     NA    NA   
 4 1     21:00 10:00
 5 1     16:00 10:00
 6 1     NA    NA   
 7 1     NA    NA   
 8 1     NA    NA   
 9 1     NA    NA   
10 1     02:00 08:00
# ... with 61,174 more rows
```

### Is there a better way to filter these data, maintaining their original hierarchy?

At the end of the day, there is a fundamental problem in your original data structure. A `data.frame` in R is implemented as a list of lists, and yet your data are stored as a data.frame of data.frames. This leads to confusion when indexing into various parts of the structure.

This is a little unorthodox, but one option is to **keep your data as a list of lists** rather than convert to a data.frame right away. Using the tools in [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) package, you can work with lists pretty easily to filter/flatten your data and then construct a data.frame from the filtered results.

For example:

```r
> ## read in yelpBusinessData without converting to data.frame
> yelpBusinessData2 <- fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]",
                                         paste(readLines(yelpBusinessDataFilePath),
                                               collapse = ",")),
                                 flatten = FALSE,
                                 simplify = FALSE)

# filter to Phoenix cities _before_ converting to a data.frame
> yelpBusinessData2 %>% 
    purrr::keep(~ .$'city' == 'Phoenix'
                  && grepl("Restaurants", .$categories)) %>% 
    jsonlite:::simplify(., flatten = T) %>% 
    dplyr::select(business_id, full_address, contains('kids')) %>% 
    str()
'data.frame':   8410 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ business_id                              : chr  "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA" "x5Mv61CnZLohZWxfCVCPTQ" "2ZnCITVa0abGce4gZ6RhIw" "EmzaQR5hQlF0WIl24NxAZA" ...
 $ full_address                             : chr  "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018" "2819 N Central Ave\nPhoenix, AZ 85004" "1850 N Central Ave\nPhoenix, AZ 85004" "132 E Washington St\nPhoenix, AZ 85004" ...
 $ attributes.Good for Kids                 : logi  NA FALSE TRUE FALSE NA NA ...
 $ attributes.Good For Kids                 : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ attributes.Hair Types Specialized In.kids: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

As a final thought, I would say, if you're still left with variable-naming issues, take a look at the [janitor](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor) package in R, specifically the `clean_names()` function. This package has some nice features for working with messy data, particularly when read in from Excel.